# java process killed by linux oomkiller, like native memory leak

Tags: java, linux, jvm, oom

I have a Java service that has been running for about ten days.
I found that it was killed by Linux's OOM killer during busy periods. The heap memory I configured for it was Xmx10G Xms6G, but the OOM killer showed that its RSS was 24.5G.

```
[6252128.258453]Out of memory: Kill process 113627 (java) score 350 or sacrifice child
[6252128.258533]Killed process 113627 (java) total-vm:50134728kB, anon-rss:25062168kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[7954659.707880][43116(bkmonitorbeat)]:gsch scan(inode=411811729,type=1,flags=0x0) -interrupted & wait(timeout=1000)
[7954659.709606][43116(bkmonitorbeat): gsch_scan(inode=411811729,type-1,flags-exe)-interrupted & waitdone
```

I restarted the process and found that the RSS in top was 30G after a few days.
I suspect there is an off-heap memory leak.

I have performed operations such as jmap dump, jstack, and pmap, and found that there is a lot of memory of 65508KB held in the process.
Then, I found many java.lang.ref.Finalizer objects in jmap, totaling 7206.

[image]

Further using OQL queries, I found that many of the referents in the Finalizer are org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement (2124),

[image]

org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement (1940),

[image]

sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl (460).

[image]

The FinalizerThread is stuck at ReferenceQueue.remove(), and I feel that there is nothing left in this queue, but there is still a lot of garbage retained in the Finalizer's linked list.

```
"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f96183e2800 nid=0x174a7 in Object.wait() [0x00007f95e4ecd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000540020d40> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)
```

I check smaps file, found that there are 322 memory blocks with an RSS value of around 64MB, which accumulates to more than 20GB of memory.

[image]

I use gdb dump an 64M memory to file, but I don't know the memory data struct，so I can't debug it.

This means that there is a possibility that the memory leak is related to glibc's malloc memory pool.

[image]

```
ldd /usr/lib64/jdk8/bin/java  

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd381f1000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0(0x00007fc9c1743000)
libjli.so => /usr/lib64/idk8/bin/../lib/amd64/ili/libjli.so(0x00007fc9c152d000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc9c1329000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/ibc.so.6 (0x00007fc9cof5b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc9c195f000)



-------
Installed Packages
glibc.x86_64  2.17-317.el
```

and my process envionment don't have MALLOC_ARENA_MAX

I restarted the service manually to prevent OOM killer from killing it again and added the -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail parameter, but after running for a few days, I still cannot see any abnormalities when using `jcmd pid VM.native_memory detail`.

[image]

I have some other debugging information
What should I do next to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: debug info : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C67MOzbOa5XCAJO3FEd92yUpwU9WAaHI?usp=drive_link

Comment: It looks like your memory leak is actually a *resource* leak.  Something is not closing database connections or statements, and they are ending up on the finalizer queue.  And the finalizer thread either cannot keep up or has been blocked.  Examine your application code that performs DB operations to make sure that connections / statements / resultsets do not leak.

Comment: why FinalizerThread queue blocked.

Comment: There is not enough information to tell why.  But its not really relevant.  Your code should not be leaking the DB / JDBC resources in the first place.

Comment: I have checked my code, and everywhere I used PreparedStatement, I closed it using DbUtils.closeQuietly(statement) from commons-dbutils:1.7. Also, this issue only occurs in one environment, while it's not happening in dozens of other environments, so I suspect it is related to the running environment. How should I further investigate?

Comment: Did you also close when the database resources when an exception is thrown?  The fact that you are using `closeQuietly` rather than *try with resources* is suspicious.

Comment: All close operations are in the finally block.

Comment: Yes ... but you can still get in trouble; e.g. if `closeQuietly` on one resource throws an exception that is not handled by the `closeQuietly` logic.  *Try with resources* solves that.  And anyway, **the evidence** suggests that something is not getting closed properly.  Trust the evidence!

Comment: *"and my process envionment don't have MALLOC_ARENA_MAX"* - so you need to set it. Or use alternative allocator, e.g. [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc)

Comment: also to add what Stephen is saying if you check code for dbutils.closeconnection 
https://github.com/apache/commons-dbutils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.java#L159

it does not handle exception occurs during close call so its better if you write your code for closing connection and probably add some loggers around it.

also if somehow you can simulate this in local then u can profile your app with viusualvm's Buffer Monitor which could help understanding if memory leak is via direct buffers allocations on off-heap